# Как заносить время выполнения запроса в таблицу?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите, как считать время выполнения запроса с последующим занесением его (времени) в отдельную таблицу в БД. И можно ли в SQL делать циклы? Например, запустить один запрос 50 раз. И каждое время занести в таблицу.
Использую MS SQL Server.

Comment: SET STATISTICS TIME чем-то не устраивает?

Comment: устраивает, как проверка времени для одного запуска. А как заносить его значение в таблицу + сделать это несколько раз (что-то вроде цикла)?

Comment: так и напишите цикл, прочите документацию по T-SQL

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15